# How to add minor tick marks to an axis besides its main tick marks?

Tags: r, plot

I have two questions.

1. I was wondering how I can **add** **two words**, one appearing in place of **"0",** the other appearing in place of **"10"** on the X and Y axes while **preserving the rest of the remaining numbers on the axes** (i.e., 1 thru 9)?
2. How can I add **minor tick marks** to both axes?

Here is **my R code**, with no success:

```
plot(0:10,0:10,type="n",axes=FALSE,xlab="JBL",ylab="PRAC")

axis(side=1,at=c("AL",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"BL"),las=1)
axis(side=2,at=c("CL",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"DL"),las=1)
box()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first question, you should use `labels` not `at`. Read `?axis`.

For the second, you can call `axis` or `Axis` twice on the same axis, but using `rug` is easier. It is a wrapper function for `Axis`. For example, you can do:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10, axes = FALSE)  ## `axes` is an argument to `plot.default`
axis(1, at = 0:10, labels = c("AL",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"BL"))
rug(x = 0:9 + 0.5, ticksize = -0.01, side = 1)
axis(2, at = 0:10, labels = c("CL",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"DL"))
rug(x = 0:9 + 0.5, ticksize = -0.01, side = 2)
```

[image]

You can see how `rug` works in its source code:

```
Axis(side = side, at = x, labels = FALSE, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = lwd, 
    col.ticks = col, tck = ticksize, ...)
```

Read `?par` for how `tck` works. The default `tck` for an axis is -0.02, so if you want a smaller one for "minor axis", set it to half. Here, the sign means direction. Positive values give ticks pointing inside the plot, while negative ones give ticks pointing outside the plot.

Answer (score 2):

For the minor ticks, you could use the `minor.tick` function from the `hmisc` package.

```
minor.tick(nx=2, ny=2, tick.ratio=0.5, x.args = list(), y.args = list())
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.1-1/topics/minor.tick